# IBM Watson Visual Recognition train own classifier in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, watson, visual-recognition

I'm trying to train/create my own classifier, I attached this code to main camera and I didn't got any response from the console nor getting any errors. Or I just doing it the wrong way?

```
public class VisualRecog : MonoBehaviour{
private VisualRecognition m_VisualRecognition = new VisualRecognition();

    void Start()
    {
        string m_positiveExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/testData/cpu_positive_examples.zip";
        string m_negativeExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/testData/negative_examples.zip";

        Dictionary<string, string> positiveExamples = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        positiveExamples.Add("cpu", m_positiveExamplesPath);
        if (!m_VisualRecognition.TrainClassifier(OnTrainClassifier, "compClassifier", positiveExamples, m_negativeExamplesPath))
            Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Train classifier failed!");
    }

    private void OnTrainClassifier(GetClassifiersPerClassifierVerbose classifier, string data)
    {

        if (classifier != null)
        {
            Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Classifier is training! " + classifier);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Failed to train classifier!");
        }
    }
}
```

by the way [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk) is the link of the Unity SDK. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please provide everything in that class including the class name. That would be helpful to help you. You may want to tag C# to get other people help you too.

Comment: edited* thanks for the heads up man! can you help me? I don`t know why I`m not getting any response in console and I don't have any errors. I really need to make this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `m_positiveExamplesPath` and `m_negativeExamplesPath`  are not valid path, you will get exception that says:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

If your did not setup your credentials then you will get the error:

> No API Key was found!

Those two problems are eliminated .

It takes about `10` seconds to get a reply from IBM server when you run this code.
Please wait for at-least `15` seconds for a reply.
The wait time actually depends on how big your *cpu_positive_examples.zip* and *negative_examples.zip* files are. Sometimes, it can take few minutes.

> I didnt got any response from the console nor getting any errors.

The problem is from the `Log` function. If you look closely, you will realize that IBM is using `Log.Debug` instead of [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html). IBM's `Log.Debug` comes from the `IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging` namespace and it doesn't show in the Editor Console tab. I can't tell if this is a bug or a feature but replacing all the `Log.Debug` with [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) should fix your problem.

I got a reply with the code below within 10 seconds(Used [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html)):

```
private VisualRecognition m_VisualRecognition = new VisualRecognition();

void Start()
{
    string positiveExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/Watson/Examples/ServiceExamples/TestData/visual-recognition-classifiers/giraffe_positive_examples.zip";
    string negativeExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/Watson/Examples/ServiceExamples/TestData/visual-recognition-classifiers/negative_examples.zip";

    Dictionary<string, string> positiveExamples = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    positiveExamples.Add("giraffe", positiveExamplesPath);

    if (!m_VisualRecognition.TrainClassifier(OnTrainClassifier, "unity-test-classifier-example", positiveExamples, negativeExamplesPath))
        Debug.Log("Train classifier failed!");
}

private void OnTrainClassifier(GetClassifiersPerClassifierVerbose classifier, string data)
{

    if (classifier != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Classifier is training! " + classifier);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to train classifier!" + data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Log.Debug()`, initialize the reactors in the beginning of your `Start()` or `Awake()` functions using

```
LogSystem.InstallDefaultReactors();
```

Alternatively, like Programmer says, use Unity's `Debug.Log()`.